# Having some Issues With Splitting Characters using preg_split

Tags: php, preg-split

I'm having a hell of a time understanding how to use preg_split()

I'm trying to do something which I'd assume is simple which is add commas to the following string: North America, Middle East, Europe

Essentially a comma after every other space (and no comma, if there is only one string item - if possible). I've only managed to get weird results, the closest being a comma after every space so it ends up being something like: North, America, Middle, East, Europe.

Any suggestions would be helpful, I've read a few articles on using preg_split but using it to do what I want still alludes me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Sorry, was in hurry. Was under the impression my description would be enough. See below.

```
The string originally looks like this: North America Europe Middle East
```

Was trying to do something a long the lines of this

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $text);
foreach($parts as $part) {
 preg_match_all('/\S+\s+\S+/', $part, $names);
 foreach($names[0] as $name) {
    echo "$name,";
 }
}
```

(credit: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?265789-How-to-add-a-linebreak-in-a-string-every-two-words)

The result is this

```
North America,Europe Middle,
```

Comment: What would happen if you had South East Asia for instance as a result? That would then throw the whole thing off

Comment: Is your list fixed? (then what's the point) or could it contain any number of names?

Comment: you better array of countries from somewhere and then search in_array and append comma if return true.

Comment: Your question is confusing because the example you give first already has commas. What does it look like BEFORE you do something to it. You repeatedly write "after every space" but you are putting commas before the spaces, not after them. Please show some input and output.

Comment: If the data comes from a db then this should be straightforward

Comment: please provide your string initially you have and what you want as result. it will help us to give answer to your question.

Comment: Hold on … You want to split on every second whitespace and join again with `, `? And then you expect `North America Europe Middle East` to turn magically into `North America, Europe, Middle East`?

Comment: I don't want a comma between Middle East and North America. If it isn't possible just say so.

Comment: Well, it looks like you've set for the wrong tool with `preg_split()`. Do your strings always look like that? It's certainly possible, but the resulting regex will be *very* complex and essentially falls into the class of "write once, never understand again."

Comment: Only for this particular output, it's being stored in the DB without commas (this is not my choice). I'm using an Joomla extension called K2. I suppose I might have to find some kind of clever work around.